# how can i use dotenv in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dotenv

i want to protect my credentials using dotev i made a .env file with REACT_APP_KEY=11234 you know, and then i acces with process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_KEY but i got the next error,

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 1:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\super\OneDrive\Escritorio\Programacion\new portfolio\portfolio\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
- install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

Comment: You can't. `fs` is part of nodeJS, and won't run client-side.

Comment: So how can i hide My credentials but netlify can acces them :(